# C program to add three integers

Tags: c

Why this simple C program does not work?

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>   
     
int t7(int i,int j,int k){    
    return (i+j+k);
}

int main(){ 
     
int a,b,c;  
printf("This program adds three integer values.\nPlease enter three integers separated by a space:\n"); 
scanf("%d %d %d\n",&a,&b,&c);   
printf("The result of %d+%d+%d is %d\n",a,b,c,t7(a,b,c)); 
     
}
```

Thank you.

I coded the whole thing, I tried to enter the three input integers on one line as well as on separate lines.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `scanf("%d %d %d\n", &a, &b, &c)` -> `scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)`

Comment: @qwsdcvghyu89 The error is that it outputs nothing.

Answer (score 1):

try just to remove \n from the scanf, it should work
[image: c program to add 3 number]

Comment: The trailing whitespace in the `scanf()` format string tells it to filter *any amount* of whitespace, but the function won't know how much that is until you actually enter a non-whitespace character, and it won't see that until you press Enter for the second time. Every character in the format string has a purpose.